# How to Symbolicate iOS Crash

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode-organizer

I'm looking to try and symbolicate my iPhone app's crash reports.

I retrieved the crash reports from the Organizer, the thing is I haven't release my app to the App Store! So can I make use of these crash reports before releasing the app and how can I do that?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: @CodaFi I am asking about using the crash reports before releasing the app

Answer (score 0):

Try such command:

```
symbolicatecrash -A -v crashlog.crash app.dSYM
```

where
app.dSYM you can get from archive of application
and
symbolicatecrash can be found in
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDeviceKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/

Comment: symbolicatecrash Not Found!!

Comment: What is `symbolicatecrash`?  Did you mean [atos](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/atos.1.html)?

Comment: `symbolicatecrash` is correct. It's a command line tool for doing what it says. I use it all of the time. For me it is a link in `/usr/local/bin` to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDeviceKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash`

Comment: Try this `ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Develope‌​r/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDeviceKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicat‌​ecrash/symbolicatecrash /usr/local.bin/symbolicatecrash`